AWS - Map Accounts and Applications with Group
I am trying to get AWS Identity store group details. Is there any way to map Groups and their accounts (Prod, Dev, or something else) and Applications available for the group/account (Snowflake, Databricks, etc... )?
I am trying this using python and boto3 and using aws commands like sso-admin, identity store and organisation.
